# IntelliJ : unable to find JAXB generated classes in sub project

Tags: java, linux, jaxb, intellij-idea, environment

I have a Maven project which has a number of child projects.  For historical reasons the project is structured like this:

```
Root
- client
- core
- model
- parent
- webapp
```

where parent is the parent pom for the root project.

This builds fine from the command line, however in IntelliJ I am trying to run my unit tests separately.

In client, I have a unit test, which when run, the Make command is giving me 86 messages ("Error: package-info.class (No such file or directory)") where it is unable to find any of the JAXB created classes.

My other colleagues are not having this problem, but our setup appears to be the same (obviously not).  I have tried 10.5.4 and 11.0.1 of IntelliJ, both give the same problem.

This is running on a Linux (Ubuntu 11.10).

Additional:

I can run a maven install from the root project fine, however, if I right click on the test class and select "Run blahblahblahtest" I get this message.  When I go to examine the configuration I have make selected (which I want, as I want it to update), but during the make I am getting the messages.

The xjc target directory (${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb) is set as a source directory.  It is only during the make cycle within intellij that it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have you added the xjc target directory to the list of your source code directories for testing.

Comment: I have checked this and it is a source directory.